# Geodesic flow and Killing vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-fields, geodesic

Let $\gamma$ be a geodesic, $\gamma'$ its tangent vector, $X$ a Killing vector field and $X_\gamma$ the restriction of $X$ to the curve $\gamma$. Let $g$ be the metric on the manifold considered.

Prove that $g(\gamma',X_\gamma)$ is constant along $\gamma$.

The definition I have for a Killing field $X$ is that it satisfied $\mathcal{L}_Xg=0$ where $\mathcal{L}$ denotes the Lie derivative.

I thought about using the induced covariant derivative on the curve $\gamma$, but all I have is a definition and no real explanation on how to put this into pratice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: You will first have to understand how the fact that $X$ is a Killing field is expressed in terms of the covariant derivative $\nabla X$. This is a standard result, it can be directly derived from exapanding the equation $0=(\mathcal L_Xg)(Y,Z)$. Having done that, you can express $\tfrac{d}{dt}g(\gamma'(\gamma(t)),X(\gamma(t)))$ in terms of covariant derivatives (along the curve) and use the equations satisfied by $\gamma'$ and by $X$ to conclude that this vanishes.

Comment: The expansion of the equation leads to $$0=(Xg)(Y,Z)-g(\mathcal{L}_X Y,Z)-g(Y,\mathcal{L}_X Z)$$ 
I have $\mathcal{L}_X Y=[X,Y]$, same for $Z$, but I do not know how to make it connect with the covariant derivative $\nabla_X$ ?
Same goes for the induced covariant derivatives, I assume it will be of the form $$\frac{d}{dt}(g(\dot{\gamma}(\gamma),X(\gamma))=g(\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}(\dot{\gamma}),X(\gamma))+g(\dot{\gamma}(\gamma),\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}(X(\gamma))$$ but I do not know how to derive this rigorously.

Comment: To connect this to $\nabla X$, you have to use that $[X,Y]=\nabla_XY-\nabla_YX$ by torsion-freeness and similarly for the other term, and simplify by using the expansion of $(Xg)(Y,Z)$ in terms of covariant derivatives. The second equation is indeed of the form you mention. This basically is compatibility of the covariant derivative along curves with the metric. How to derive it rigorously depends a bit on the setting you are working in.

Comment: Okay, I think I got it. We have $$\nabla_X g(Y,Z)=(Xg)(Y,Z)-g(\nabla_X Y,Z)-g(Y,\nabla_X Z)=0$$ and $$\mathcal{L}_Xg(Y,Z)=(Xg)(Y,Z)-g(\nabla_X Y-\nabla_Y X,Z)-g(Y,\nabla_X Z-\nabla_Z X)$$ and this leads to $$\mathcal{L}_Xg(Y,Z)=g(\nabla_Y X,Z)+g(Y,\nabla_Z X)$$ right ? Then, we use the fact that $\gamma$ is a geodesic so that $\nabla_\dot{\gamma}\dot{\gamma}=0$ and the symmetry of $g$ and that $X$ is a Killing field so that $g(\dot{\gamma},\nabla_\dot{\gamma}X)=-g(\nabla_\dot{\gamma}X,\dot{\gamma})=-g(\dot{\gamma},\nabla_\dot{\gamma}X)$ so that the term vanishes. Is that correct ?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

Here's an overkill solution: the flow of $X$ consists of isometries, and so it preserves the Lagrangian $L\colon TM \to \Bbb R$ given by $L(x,v) = g_x(v,v)/2$, whose fiber derivative is $\mathbb{F}L(x,v) = g_x(v,\cdot)$. Critical points of the action functional of $L$ are geodesics, so *Noether's Theorem* says that along geodesics, the Noether charge $$\mathbb{F}L(x,v)X_x = g_x(v,X_x)$$is constant. So $t \mapsto g_{\gamma(t)}(\gamma'(t), X_{\gamma(t)})$ is constant if $X$ is Killing and $\gamma$ is a geodesic.